# How do I join points from a time series in a ggplot representing two variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting multiple time series (17) in which there are 2 variables, which means 2 values for each year for each time series, and I want to plot one variable according to the other. And then I want to join the points with lines in order of year, so that each time series will have a corresponding line joining all their points.
Does anyone know how to do the line-joining part?

I am working with ggplot, here's some script, a plot I have and a screenshot of my data:

```
moyvar_plot <- ggplot(moyvar, aes(x=value, y=var$value, group=programme, col=variable)) +
geom_text(aes(label=variable), size=3) +
xlim(0.85, 1.4) +
ylim(0, 1.0) +
ggtitle("Variances sur 5 ans glissants des taux de croissance des nombres de couples \n en fonction des moyennes sur 5 ans glissants des taux de croissance des nombres de couples") +
xlab("Moyenne") + 
ylab("Variance")        

print(moyvar_plot)
```

In which "variable" is the year number, and I am trying to plot `var$value` according to "value".

I have tried grouping my data according to "programme", which is the identifier of my different time series, and adding a geom_line, but it connects the point in order of the x axis, and I want them connected in order of year...
This is the dataset:
[image]

This the plot:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by connecting them "in order of year" and not by x-axis? Like, sequentially 1-2-3-4-5-6-...39? But there are many of each year number `variable`, so do you want them to be grouped by `programme` as well? As in, some lines are supposed to connect the `variable` numbers sequentially for each `programme` group?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `geom_path()` to connect "the observations in the order in which they appear in the data" (from its R documentation).

Here is an example that is similar to your data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2021) # for reproducible random values in the example data

moyvar <- data.frame(programme = factor(rep(c('a','b','c'), each = 4)), 
    variable = 1:4, value = runif(12), variance = runif(12))

ggplot(moyvar, aes(x = value, y = variance, col = programme)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = variable), size = 6) + 
    geom_path()
```

[image]

Each `programme` line goes sequentially from `variable` "1" to `variable` "4".

*However, duly note* that if your `moyvar$variable`, for some reason, is not ordered sequentially in the data set (e.g., if the data set is sorted by `moyvar$value`), the line paths will not connect the `variable` numbers sequentially.

You can resolve it by reordering the rows before you plot. Here are a couple ways to make sure your data is sorted as desired:

```r
moyvar <- moyvar[order(moyvar$variable),]

#or

moyvar <- dplyr::arrange(moyvar, variable) # requires `dplyr` package
```